# Sum Hours:Minutes:Seconds in Java script

Tags: javascript

how can I sum hours:minutes:seconds in JavaScript.
I mean by
04:32:05
03:14:03
To get
07:46:08

Ive tried

```
    var time1 = "01:00:01";
    var time2 = "01:00:10";
    var time3 = "01:54:00";
    var time4 = "01:30:00";
    var time5 = "01:00:00";
    var time6 = "01:00:00";
    var time7 = "01:00:00";
    
    var hour=0;
    var minute=0;
    var second=0;
    
    var splitTime1= time1.split(':');
    var splitTime2= time2.split(':');
    var splitTime3= time3.split(':');
    var splitTime4= time4.split(':');
    var splitTime5= time5.split(':');
    var splitTime6= time6.split(':');
    var splitTime7= time7.split(':');
    
    hour = parseInt(splitTime1[0]) + parseInt(splitTime2[0])  + parseInt(splitTime3[0])  + parseInt(splitTime4[0])  + parseInt(splitTime5[0])  + parseInt(splitTime6[0]) + parseInt(splitTime7[0]) 
    minute = parseInt(splitTime1[1]) + parseInt(splitTime2[1]) + parseInt(splitTime3[1]) + parseInt(splitTime4[1]) + parseInt(splitTime5[1]) + parseInt(splitTime6[1]) + parseInt(splitTime7[1])
    hour = hour + minute/60;
    minute = minute%60;
    second = parseInt(splitTime1[2]) + parseInt(splitTime2[2]) + parseInt(splitTime3[2]) 
    + parseInt(splitTime4[2]) + parseInt(splitTime5[2]) + parseInt(splitTime6[2]) + 
    parseInt(splitTime7[2]) 
    minute = minute + second/60;
    second = second%60;
    
   console.log(hour+ ":" + minute + ":"+ second)
```

The output I get is 8.4:24.183333333333334:11 instad of 08:24:11
any suggestions?

Comment: When you see the same code over and over you should look into making functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello hope this answer will help you, I recommand to replace your bottom part (where you calculate) I do pretty much the same thing, but in the good order and with round to avoid decimals problems

```js
var time1 = "01:00:01";
    var time2 = "01:00:10";
    var time3 = "01:54:00";
    var time4 = "01:30:00";
    var time5 = "01:00:00";
    var time6 = "01:00:00";
    var time7 = "01:00:00";
    
    var hour=0;
    var minute=0;
    var second=0;

    
    var splitTime1= time1.split(':');
    var splitTime2= time2.split(':');
    var splitTime3= time3.split(':');
    var splitTime4= time4.split(':');
    var splitTime5= time5.split(':');
    var splitTime6= time6.split(':');
    var splitTime7= time7.split(':');


    var allTimes = [splitTime1, splitTime2, splitTime3, splitTime4, splitTime5, splitTime6, splitTime7]

    allTimes.forEach(element => {
        hour += parseInt(element[0])
        minute += parseInt(element[1])
        second += parseInt(element[2])
    })

    minute += Math.round(second / 60); 
    second = second % 60;
    hour += Math.round(minute / 60);
    minute = minute % 60

    
   console.log(hour+ ":" + minute + ":"+ second)
```

Answer (score 1):

your making it very complex, you can reduce this by converting into Date objects and then add each date to get the sum of all dates
[Understanding Date and Time in JavaScript](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-date-and-time-in-javascript#:%7E:text=The%20Date%20Object%20%20%20%20Date%20Creation,date%20based%20on%20specified%20date%20and%20...%20)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you are including the decimal point

```
hour = hour + minute/60;
```

you need to floor it.

```
hour = hour + Math.floor(minute/60);
```

Now how to do it without a lot of repetitive code.

```js
function toSeconds(s) {
  const parts = s.split(':');
  return +parts[0] * 3600 + +parts[1] * 60 + +parts[2];
}

function secondsToHHMMSS(secs) {
  return Math.floor(secs / 3600).toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + 
         (Math.floor(secs / 60) % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + 
         (secs % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
}


const timestamps = ["01:00:01", "01:00:10", "01:54:00", "01:30:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00"];

const totalSeconds = timestamps.reduce(function(total, ts) {
  return total + toSeconds(ts); 
}, 0);

const result = secondsToHHMMSS(totalSeconds);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum of times then you should try this

```
var addTime = function (time1, time2) {
//   convert to ms
  var dateObject1 = new Date(time1).valueOf();
  var dateObject2 = new Date(time2).valueOf();
  
  return dateObject1 + dateObject2;
}


var time1 = new Date().setHours(4, 32, 5, 0);
var time2 = new Date().setHours(3, 14, 3, 0);

var sum = new Date(addTime(time1, time2));

var getFormatedTime = function (time) {
  return time.getHours()+':'+time.getMinutes()+':'+time.getSeconds()
}


console.log(getFormatedTime(sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should look into is using an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), since you have a number of objects of the same kind.

You should ideally have something like,

```
const times = ["04:32:05", "03:14:03", ...]
```

Once you have that, this problem *reduces* to a classic use-case for the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function.
The reduce function operates on an array and accumulates the value of the operation every step to yield one value at the end.

Here's an example solution for your problem

```js
const times = ["04:32:05", "03:14:03"]
//const times = ["01:00:01", "01:00:10","01:54:00","01:30:00"]

let finalSum = times.reduce((sum, curr) => {
  //Obtain the current timestamp as an array of numbers
  //[HRS, MINS, SECS]
  let currTimeStamp = curr.split(":").map(token => parseInt(token));

  //Add the current seconds to the total seconds so far
  sum[2] += currTimeStamp[2];
  //See how many minutes you got leftover as a result of that addition
  const leftOverMins = Math.floor(sum[2] / 60);
  //Mod by 60, to keep the seconds under 60
  sum[2] %= 60;

  //Add the leftover minutes to the sum operation for minutes
  sum[1] += (currTimeStamp[1] + leftOverMins);
  //Similar procedure as above
  const leftOverHours = Math.floor(sum[1] / 60);
  sum[1] %= 60;


  sum[0] += (currTimeStamp[0] + leftOverHours);
  sum[0] %= 24;

  return sum
}, [0, 0, 0])


console.log(finalSum.join(":"))
```